# Proof Verification - Plane containing intersection of two other planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-verification, vectors

I haven't seen anyone on this site post anything about this proof yet, but feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Here is the problem from "Linear Algebra: Geometric Approach" by Shifrin and Adams:

> Assume $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are nonparallel vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (A) Show that the plane $ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}=0 $ contains the intersection of the planes $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{x}=0$ and $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{x}=0$ if and only if (B) $\vec{a} = s\vec{b}+t\vec{c}$ for some $s,t \in \mathbb{R}^3$, both not $0$.

So I need to prove that $A \leftrightarrow B$.

Proving $B\rightarrow A$ is simple. Just substitute $\vec{a}$ with $s\vec{b}+t\vec{c}$ and take the dot product with any vector in the intersection of the line.

However, for $A\rightarrow B$, I did this:

Both of the planes $\mathscr{P}_b : \vec{b}\cdot\vec{x}=0$ and $\mathscr{P}_c :\vec{c}\cdot\vec{x}=0$ pass through the origin, so the line can be described as $\mathscr{l}: t\vec{v}$. Since the vector $\vec{v}$ is in both of the planes, that implies that both $\vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are orthogonal to $\vec{v}$. So $\vec{b}, \vec{c}$ span the plane that is orthogonal to the line $\mathscr{l}$. Now since $\mathscr{P}_a$ contains $\mathscr{l}$, $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{v}=0 \implies \vec{a} \in \text{Span}\lbrace \vec{b},\vec{c}\rbrace \implies \vec{a} = s\vec{b}+t\vec{c}$ for some $s,t \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Is this a valid proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK, but it's a bit formal and overcomplicated for my tastes. It depends whether you're taking a linear algebra class or a geometry class. Your proof is written using linear algebra jargon, which is fine if that's the class you're taking. Geometry folks (like me) would probably express the reasoning as follows:

The vector $\vec{a}$ is perpendicular to the line of intersection of the two planes, therefore it's coplanar with their normal vectors $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$. So $\vec{a}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$.

This is all in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so it would be a good idea to draw a picture. Your linear algebra teacher will say "it's not a proof". This is true, but it will help you understand the situation.